# Is it okay to use "delete this;" on an object that inherits from a Thread class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, pthreads, delete-operator

In general, if you have a class that inherits from a `Thread` class, and you want instances of that class to automatically deallocate after they are finished running, is it okay to `delete this`?

Specific Example:

In my application I have a `Timer` class with one `static` method called `schedule`. Users call it like so:

```
Timer::schedule((void*)obj, &callbackFunction, 15); // call callbackFunction(obj) in 15 seconds
```

The `schedule` method creates a `Task` object (which is similar in purpose to a Java TimerTask object). The `Task` class is `private` to the `Timer` class and inherits from the `Thread` class (which is implemented with pthreads). So the `schedule` method does this:

```
Task *task = new Task(obj, callback, seconds);
task->start(); // fork a thread, and call the task's run method
```

The `Task` constructor saves the arguments for use in the new thread. In the new thread, the task's `run` method is called, which looks like this:

```
void Timer::Task::run() {
    Thread::sleep(this->seconds);
    this->callback(this->obj);
    delete this;
}
```

Note that I can't make the `task` object a stack allocated object because the new thread needs it. Also, I've made the `Task` class `private` to the `Timer` class to prevent others from using it.

I am particularly worried because deleting the `Task` object means deleting the underlying `Thread` object. The only state in the `Thread` object is a `pthread_t` variable. Is there any way this could come back to bite me? Keep in mind that I do not use the `pthread_t` variable after the `run` method finishes.

I could bypass calling `delete this` by introducing some sort of state (either through an argument to the `Thread::start` method or something in the `Thread` constructor) signifying that the method that is forked to should `delete` the object that it is calling the `run` method on. However, the code seems to work as is.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the 'delete this' is safe, as long as you don't do anything else afterwards in the run() method (because all of the Task's object's member variables, etc, will be freed memory at that point).

I do wonder about your design though... do you really want to be spawning a new thread every time someone schedules a timer callback?  That seems rather inefficient to me.  You might look into using a thread pool (or even just a single persistent timer thread, which is really just a thread pool of size one), at least as an optimization for later.   (or better yet, implement the timer functionality without spawning extra threads at all... if you're using an event loop with a timeout feature (like select() or WaitForMultipleObjects()) it is possible to multiplex an arbitrary number of independent timer events inside a single thread's event loop)

Comment: I think I'll end up using a persistent timer thread. This isn't a really serious project, I don't need to worry about being that efficient.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing particularly horrible about `delete this;` as long as you assure that:

1. the object is always dynamically allocated, and
2. no member of the object is ever used after it's deleted.

The first of these is the difficult one. There are steps you can take (e.g. making the ctor private) that help, but nearly anything you do *can* be bypassed if somebody tries hard enough.

That said, you'd probably be better off with some sort of thread pool. It tends to be more efficient and scalable.

Edit: When I talked about being bypassed, I was thinking of code like this:

```
class HeapOnly {
  private:
    HeapOnly () {} // Private Constructor.
    ~HeapOnly () {} // A Private, non-virtual destructor.
  public:
    static HeapOnly * instance () { return new HeapOnly(); }
    void destroy () { delete this; }  // Reclaim memory.
};
```

That's about as good of protection as we can provide, but getting around it is trivial:

```
int main() { 
    char buffer[sizeof(HeapOnly)];

    HeapOnly *h = reinterpret_cast<HeapOnly *>(buffer);
    h->destroy(); // undefined behavior...
    return 0;
}
```

When it's direct like this, this situation's pretty obvious. When it's spread out over a larger system, with (for example) an object factory actually producing the objects, and code somewhere else entirely allocating the memory, etc., it can become much more difficult to track down.

I originally said "there's nothing particularly horrible about `delete this;`", and I stand by that -- I'm not going back on that and saying it shouldn't be used. I am trying to warn about the kind of problem that can arise with it if other code "Doesn't play well with others."

Comment: @e8johan: but the class can define all constructors private and only construct the object dynamically within the `schedule` static method, so from the class point of view it is achievable (and not even hard).

Comment: Of course, you are right. Let's just not forget the copy operator as well.

Answer (score 1):

If all you ever do with a `Task` object is `new` it, `start` it, and then `delete` it, why would you need an object for it anyway? Why not simply implement a function which does what `start` does (minus object creation and deletion)?

Comment: I need an object to hold the 'seconds', 'obj', and 'callback' data. In pthreads, you can only pass one argument to the forked function. I'm passing a pointer to the Task object. Is there another way to pass the data?

Comment: @Ryan L Brown: The usual C way is creating a struct to hold the data and pass a pointer into the function. As you pointed out, you cannot use the stack to hold the struct (unless you have a really strong guarantee that you will not leave the scope while the thread is running, but you can dynamically allocate it and have the thread downcast and delete when it is done with it.

Comment: You can also consider using a higher level thread library (I would suggest boost::thread as it is the closest interface to what C++0x threads will look like.

Comment: @David Rodriguez: A struct is (almost) exactly the same as a class. I don't see the difference between the way I'm doing it now, and your suggestion. About boost: I have to use pthreads, but good suggestion for anyone else.

Comment: @Ryan L Brown: a class and a struct are the same thing in C++, I was just pointing out the C way of passing arguments to the pthread library. Also note that there is one specific difference in the C approach as compared to your approach: the code operates on the struct from outside, the free/delete is called from a free function, as compared to deleting your own instance. As others pointed out, in your case there is no problem in deleting this (suicide is not a sin in C++), but you risk adding code that access members of the instance after the delete at one point or another. I did it myself.

Answer (score 1):

`delete this` frees the memory you have explicitly allocated for the thread to use, but what about the resources allocated by the OS or pthreads library, such as the thread's call stack and kernel thread/process structure (if applicable)? If you never call [`pthread_join()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join) or [`pthread_detach()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_detach) and you never set the [detachstate](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_attr_setdetachstate), I think you still have a memory leak.

It also depends on how your `Thread` class is designed to be used. If it calls `pthread_join()` in its destructor, that's a problem.

If you use `pthread_detach()` (which your `Thread` object might already be doing), and you're careful not to dereference `this` after deleting `this`, I think this approach should be workable, but others' suggestions to use a longer-lived thread (or thread pool) are well worth considering.